# Set cursor blink rate in Adobe Brackets

Tags: javascript, editor, adobe-brackets

I know Brackets editor uses CodeMirror and you can change cursor blink rate in CodeMirror with `cursorBlinkRate`. But how i can do this in Brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brackets extension [Cursor options](https://github.com/maupin/brackets-cursor) does it.